# Finding printf() calls outside #ifdef statements using Regex (POSIX)

Tags: c, regex, posix, c-preprocessor

I've been asked by a co-worker to come up with a regular expression (POSIX syntax) for finding calls to `printf(...);` -- in a c-code file -- which aren't in a `#ifdef` ... `#endif` scope.

However, seeing as I am only just learning about Regexes at Uni, I'm not completely confident in it.

The scenario would look something like this:

```
possibly some code
printf(some_parameters);  // This should match
possibly more code

#ifdef DEBUG
possibly some code
printf(some_parameters);  // This shouldn't match
possibly more code
#endif

possibly some code
printf(some_parameters);  // This should also match
possibly more code
```

Note that a c-file may not contain a #ifdef/#endif statement at all, in which case all calls to `printf();` should match.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
(?<!(#ifdef [A-Å0-9]+)).*printf\(.*\);.*(?!(#endif))
```

...along with playing around with the position (and even inclusion/exclusion) of .*

Any help or hints appreciated.

Comment: FYI: not possible with normal POSIX extended REs, as they can't match nested structures (so matching `#ifdef...#ifdef...#endif...#endif` fails).

Comment: Assume that case doesn't exist.

Comment: Then maybe you have to deal with crap like `#    ifdef X`, `#if defined(X)`, `#/*blargh*/ifdef X`, `# if ! defined(X)`, `#ifndef X`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not a good way to approach this. They don't deal well with multi line searches and they are limited in the patterns they can express, e.g. arbitrary nesting is impossible to specify with regexen.

The proper way to tackle this problem is using tools designed to deal with conditional compilation directives in C code. This would be the C preprocessor of your compiler, or a specialized tool like `unifdef`:

```
$ unifdef -UDEBUG file.c | grep printf
printf(some_parameters);  // This should match
printf(some_parameters);  // This should also match
```

From the manual:

```
UNIFDEF(1)                BSD General Commands Manual               UNIFDEF(1)

NAME
     unifdef, unifdefall — remove preprocessor conditionals from code

SYNOPSIS
     unifdef [-ceklst] [-Ipath -Dsym[=val] -Usym -iDsym[=val] -iUsym] ... [file]
     unifdefall [-Ipath] ... file

DESCRIPTION
     The unifdef utility selectively processes conditional cpp(1) directives.
     It removes from a file both the directives and any additional text that
     they specify should be removed, while otherwise leaving the file alone.

     The unifdef utility acts on #if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #elif, #else, and #endif
     lines, and it understands only the commonly-used subset of the expression
     syntax for #if and #elif lines.  It handles integer values of symbols
     defined on the command line, the defined() operator applied to symbols
     defined or undefined on the command line, the operators !, <, >, <=, >=,
     ==, !=, &&, ||, and parenthesized expressions.  Anything that it does not
     understand is passed through unharmed.  It only processes #ifdef and
     #ifndef directives if the symbol is specified on the command line, other‐
     wise they are also passed through unchanged.  By default, it ignores #if
     and #elif lines with constant expressions, or they may be processed by
     specifying the -k flag on the command line.
```

Comment: A followup question: Will there be any way of telling WHERE in the code those printf calls are? Or even a way of removing them (replacing them with blanks?), since I imagine that's the motive behind my co-worker's request. (Our production people frowns upon printf calls outside debug code)

Comment: Use `unifdef -l ... | grep -n printf` so you can determine the line number in the original file on which the `printf` occurs.

Comment: Awesome, I'll pass that on. Thanks a ton! :>

Answer (score 0):

Don't need regex.

```
cpp -D<your #define options here> | grep printf
```

Comment: Using cpp might be much harder in practice. It would also process #include directives and perform macro replacement, possibly inserting or removing printfs.

Comment: That's what `-nostdinc` is for. And, arguably, finding `printf`s in expanded macros might be construed a feature...

Comment: But you are making the assumption 'all the world's a gcc'. And `-nostdinc` sems like the wrong option--it just says to skip the standard directories.

Comment: If you provide no more include options, that removes all the include directories.

Comment: It causes heaps of errors due to include files not found along `x.c:1:19: error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h`. I don't deem that acceptable.

Comment: `2>/dev/null`. But really, `unifdef` is a nice solution (and I voted for it), so let's not argue about this.